# How to wait for Firebase realtime database iteration to stop?

Tags: javascript, firebase, foreach

So I have the following code:

```
var users = db.ref("/usr")
var userE = "a@a.com"
var counter = 0;
users.once("value").then(function(snap) {
   snap.forEach(function(childSnapshot){
     var data = childSnapshot.val()
     var emailA = data.email
     if(emailA == userE){
       counter++
     }
   })
})
console.log(counter)
```

My problem isn't with the iteration of it, as it seems to do that. However, what I am confused on is that even when `userE` is present in the database, my counter doesn't seem to increment (meaning it seems to always stay at 0); it just seems that the console.log is happening before the `.forEach` loop completes. How can I fix this? If there is no real fix, how can I verify that a user's email is not already in a database?

Also, I've made sure that the value of `emailA` is indeed an email from the database. It seems that the actual problem is just a matter of waiting until the loop completes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is not with **Firebase** but with async operations.
Check [this](https://medium.com/javascript-scene/master-the-javascript-interview-what-is-a-promise-27fc71e77261) to learn how Promises in JS work!

Here is an example with ES6 syntax:

```
const dbRef = db.ref("/usr");
const email = "a@a.com";

const checkIfUserIsInDatabase = async (users, email) => {
    let result = false;
    
    const data = await users.once("value");

    data.forEach(user => {
        if(user.val().email === email) result = true;
    })

    return result;
};

checkIfUserIsInDatabase(dbRef, email).then((isUserInDatabase) => {
    if(isUserInDatabase) {
        console.log("Hell yeah!");
    } else {
        console.log("No :(");
    }
});
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I didn't think about using an async function :facepalm: but this is an amazing response, and it does work as expected. Thanks a ton, and welcome to the community!

Answer (score 3):

your problem isn't with `firebase` but how async / promises work in javascript.

JS doesn't wait for code in promises to get executed so your log is done before the `.then` call even begin !

To make things a bit clearer you should move all your `counter` code inside the callback:

```js
var users = db.ref("/usr")
var userE = "a@a.com"
users.once("value").then(function(snap) {
   // once this callback is executed we are back to synchronous code
   var counter = 0;
   snap.forEach(function(childSnapshot){
     // this forEach callback is actually synchronous, unlike .then promises
     var data = childSnapshot.val()
     var emailA = data.email
     if(emailA == userE){
       counter++
     }
   })

   // we can now access our counter
   console.log(counter);
})

console.log('this will be log before the counter!')
```